# Stand-alone php script: Insert query works fine for large content (300kb), but typo3 doesn't save the same content

Tags: php, mysql, sql, typo3

I have standalone PHP script which inserts my 300kb of HTML data into MYSQL table correctly

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tt_content 
          (pid, CType, bodytext, cruser_id, header) 
        VALUES 
          (26124, 'text', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."', 1,'" . $heading . "')";
```

But Typo3 doesn't save the same content inserted via its editor.

It seems to be the problem with my typo3 configuration or typo3 problem?

Comment: What editor do you mean? If you use the HTML-Content-Element it should be not modified.

Comment: is it an extension? You might need to change the  max content length in the tca.php file for that field.

Comment: I am using rtehtmlarea 2.0.9, which is comes with typo3 by default. I have checked with rtehtmlarea's tce.php for max content length, i dont have such limits for bodytext field. Any Idea ?. Same problem with HTML-content-element type.

Answer (score 0):

The content of an RTE field is parsed on the way into the database. So perhaps you run out of time (max_execution_time is to low) or out of memory (memory_limit is to low). Try to adjust that settings.

Comment: I have following values in php.ini

max_execution_time = 320 
memory_limit = 1024M

Comment: what happens, if you deactivate the RTE? Perhaps something with Database connection UTF-8 vs. latin1? Did you tried different browsers?

Comment: I have UTF-8 Enabled, but mysql database is in latin1. Will that cause any problem.  If so how can i solve this please?

I have executed following query to find encoding of database.

show create database demo ;

CREATE DATABASE `demo` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */

Comment: I have configured UTF-8 for typo3 pages, MYSQL database is latin1;

Comment: Did you tried different browsers, did you try to deactivate RTE?

Comment: It works fine when i deactivate the RTE with major browsers. RTE.default.disabled = 1.

Comment: Any configuration needed for RTE?

Comment: perhaps, your html code is not valid? There is a function to clean up your markup. You do not try to insert an HTML-document (with <body> Tag). The body-tag is not allowed, so the whole content in there will be removed.

Comment: I have tried with Normal content with out any tags only with p tag. Still problem exists.

Comment: "normal content" means only a-z, no special characters? And this normal content works if you disable the RTE? Is there a limit, how many characters works?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5622/discussion-between-user911282-and-maholtz)